# returning with this.state a variable on react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`this.state.onlyvar.TheName` is showing up as `undefined` and I don't know why.

```
import  React, { Component } from 'react';

class Thevar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        onlyvar: [{
            TheName:"getter Name"
            }]
    }
  }
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            TheOnlyVar: <p>{console.log(this.state.onlyvar.TheName)}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
}

export default Thevar;
```

Comment: `onlyvar` is an array.

Comment: try returning onlyvar[0].TheName, although better to change it to just an object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code there are two mistakes:

1. `onlyvar` is an array, to access its items you should use an index to specify which item you want, in this case, the first (and only) item.
2. `console.log()` prints the value in the console, not on the page.

Here is the corrected code:

```
return (
    <div>
        TheOnlyVar: <p>{this.state.onlyvar[0].TheName}</p>
    </div>
)
```